# Gradual opacity change in jquery

Tags: jquery, opacity, fade

Hi I'm trying to recreate the scroll down indicator (3 circles at the bottom of the image) from this [website](http://www.uppercase.no/#/philosophy).  I have a basic [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/He7u9/5/) so far. Whats the best way to get the gradual change in opacity in jQuery and then hide it and keep repeating?

```
<div class="scrollDown">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>



.scrollDown {
margin:200px auto 0;
width:5px;
padding-bottom:50px;
}

.scrollDown span {
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10x;
-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px;
border-radius: 10px 10px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
margin-bottom:3px;
height: 5px;
width: 5px;
background: #000;
opacity: 1;
display: block;
}



setTimeout(function(){
        $('#scrollDown span').fadeOut();}, 2000);
```

So im looking for each of the spans to gradually fade out at different times not all at the same time.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what exactly are you trying to make happen? I'm having trouble figuring out what your issue is.

Comment: Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will get you closer to solving your problem:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $("span").each(function(index) {
     $(this).delay(400*index).fadeTo("slow",0.5,function(){
     $(this).delay(200*index).fadeTo("slow",1);
     });;
  });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/He7u9/6/)**

***Disregard:*** *You can use `.scroll()` and `.fadeTo()`
I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here is an updated [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/He7u9/2/).*

Comment: ive updated the post so its a little more specific :)